# Chrome favicon overriding issue

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Html page which consists of two different favicons references, I want to override the second favicon (favicon2) with the first one. i.e :

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

In Firefox favicon2 is showing but in Chrome and IE favicon1 is displaying, how can I make Chrome display favicon2?

Please help me this. I am stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add your favicon in the root of the folder and update the url path to favicon.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('myIcon').href = "favicon2.ico";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link id="myIcon" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute of the icon.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```